# What is this equivalence relation explicitly?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Let $S \colon = \{ \  (x,y) \in \mathbf{R}^2 \  | \ \  y = x +1, \ \ 0 < x < 1 \  \}$, and let $T$ be the intersection of all the equivalence relation on the plane that contain $S$.

Then how to write $T$ explicitly as a set?

Comment: what is the intersection of two equivalent relations? Who is containing $S$, the plane or the relation?

Comment: You should start by figuring out, for a given real number $t$, what elements of $\mathbb R$ must be equivalent to $t$ under any equivalence relation containing $S$. That will give you an excellent hint for what $T$ must be.

Comment: Emanuele Paolini, an equivalence relation, like any relation, on a set $A$ is after all a subset $E$ of the Cartesian product $A \times A$; it could be described as a subset that satisfies (i) $(a,a) \in E$ for each $a \in A$; (ii) if $(a,b) \in E$, then $(b,a) \in E$ for any $a$, $b \in A$; and (iii) if $(a,b) \in E$ and $(b,c) \in E$, then $(a,c) \in E$. And, I'm seeking the set that is the intersection of all the equivalence relations on the plane each of which contains the set $S$ as a subset.

Comment: Greg Martin, would you please elaborate on your hint; I'm sorry, but I'm afraid I'm unable to see your point.

Comment: $T$ is actually the intersection of all equivalence relations on $\Bbb R$ that contain $S$: subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ are equivalence relations on $\Bbb R$, not on $\Bbb R^2$.